# keep same nav bar color with pushview controller

Tags: ios, swift, pushviewcontroller

I have an application with a navigation controller that connects to the UIViewcontrollerA. Inside UIViewcontrollerA I have a tableview, and when a user clicks on a cell they are taken to UIViewcontrollerB. UIViewcontrollerB does not have any connections to UIViewcontrolleA in the storyboard or to any navigation controller. The issue that I am having is that on click to go to UIViewcontrollerB, the navbar loses its color value. Is there a way to pass in the value form UIViewcontrollerA to UIViewcontrollerB without having to manually set it in UIViewcontrollerB?
Thank you for your help!

Code:

```
if let vc: UIViewcontrollerB = stbrd.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: UIViewcontrollerB.UIViewcontrollerBIdentifier) as? UIViewcontrollerB {
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: How have you set the colour of the navbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that in the identity inspector for UIViewControllerB that you haven't disabled the Navigation bar. I had this issue earlier, and I had to set the Top Bar to 'Inferred'. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the tip! This was the issue! I was overriding nav bar with my UIViewControllerB.

Answer (score 1):

To update the navigation bar appearance on all the view controllers, write the following lines of code in appDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
   UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```